# Double and Boolean attribute problem in JSON model

Tags: android, json, android-studio, model-view-controller

In advance I thank all those who can see my publication. I have this JSON that I get in response, where an object in a list receives in one of it's attributes a data type Double and this same also receives a Boleean data in another object of the same list, I'm using the retrofit library, but gives me the following error:

> Expected a double but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 1831 path $ .extension_attributes.carrousel [0] .related_products [0] .price_regular

This tells me that the problem is in the "price_regular" attribute, it's the  first time something like this happens to me.

This is the JSON

```
"related_products": [
                {
                    "name": "AZALEIA 239-036",
                    "price_regular": false,
                    "price_special": null,
                    "price": 0,                    
                },
                {            
                    "name": "AZALEIA 239-038",
                    "price_regular": 69.9,
                    "price_special": null,
                    "price": 69.9,                        
                },
]
```

You can see there it's shown how it receives a double and a false in the attribute `price_regular`, my model will generate it in the following way.

```
@SerializedName(Constants.Api.RelatedProducts.NAME)
private String name;
@SerializedName(Constants.Api.RelatedProducts.PRICE_REGULAR)
private Double priceRegular;
@SerializedName(Constants.Api.RelatedProducts.PRICE_SPECIAL)
private Double priceSpecial;
@SerializedName(Constants.Api.RelatedProducts.PRICE)
private Double price;

 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Double getPriceRegular() {
    return priceRegular;
}

public void setPriceRegular(Double priceRegular) {
    this.priceRegular = priceRegular;
}

public Double getPriceSpecial() {
    return priceSpecial;
}

public void setPriceSpecial(Double priceSpecial) {
    this.priceSpecial = priceSpecial;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all type your prim **priceRegular** as an **Object** in yor model class like;

```
@SerializedName(Constants.Api.RelatedProducts.PRICE_REGULAR)
private Object priceRegular;
```

And change your getter of course as an Object like;

```
public Object getPriceRegular() {
    return priceRegular;
}
```

Now we are done with your model class. Time to parse your data :)

In your json response you need to parse it like

```
if(response. getPriceRegular() instanceof Boolean) {
//Do something
} else if (response. getPriceRegular() instanceof Double) {
//Do something
} else {
//Do something
}
```

I think this will be work for your story.